# Can this combination work? SHIMANO RD M5120 with a M6000 drivetrain?

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, crankset, derailleur-rear, drivetrain

I definitely dislike the new proposals made by SHIMANO, but I have found that RD M5120 can be used in 10 or 11 speeds, it would only depend on changing the chain.
Well, my doubt arises due to the fact that this derailleur maximum capacity is 41 teeth (maximum front difference is 10 according to this, we can see it in 24-34, 26-36), and I if I want to use the MT500-3 CRANKSET (Deore M6000 Series), that maximum capacity would be 49 teeth.
Well, what would happen if I tried this combination?
Would there be a problem with the chain or something?
Take into account that this RD can be used with 10 and 11 speed chains.

Thanks for helping me.

[image: M6000 GROUPSET with intruder RD M5120]

Comment: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/77163/shimano-rd-m5120-and-10-11-speed-compatibility - 10 and 11 speed have different pull ratios but 'it works' because they accept a the last cog out by around 20%.  At the price point you are looking at, might be better to look at other than Shimano for what you want (e.g Advent) and get much better end result

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you exceed rear derailleur capacity has been explained in this question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/82744/54500

But the thing is that you don't need a clutch derailleur with a 2x or 3x system. If you really want to use this kind of crankset with a 10-speed system, your best bet is to take a derailleur from the Trekking range (Deore or XT): they have 47-tooth capacities. But they can only take 11-36 cassettes Using the 40T cassette you suggested "will work", but shifting won't be accurate. Note that even with a 36T cassette, you'll already be in the kind of ratios where keeping the balance is not obvious, so the benefit of the 40T is limited.

Or another option is the Microshift Advent (9-speed): the long cage version has also a capacity of 47T, and can take cassettes between 42 and 46 teeth.